# Related posts from the blogosphere - dynamic integration of Google Blogsearch RSS on wordpress category pages

Tags: wordpress, rss, categories

I'm looking for a method to put the three latest "news" from Google Blogsearch/Twitter search feeds into the bottom of category Pages. Maybe like this (assuming we're on the archive page for the "Sports" category):

What others say about "Sport":

1. Instapundit - Michael Jordan Comeback!
2. Huffington post - Michael Jordan Comeback!
3. Crazyguy - Michael Jordan Comeback!

So we all know that you can put

```
<?php include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php');
wp_rss('pathtofeed.com', 3); ?>
```

in a `template-file` and it will list the latest three items of a feed.

I would like to put the path to the feed of a query to Google Blogsearch, e.g. [http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=en&q=sport&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss][1]

Works fine. But I would like to replace the `sport query` with the template tag for the category title - so it dynamically queries Google for a RSS-feed of `sport searches`. I've tried this:

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php');
wp_rss('www.blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=en&q=<?php single_cat_title() ?>&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss', 3); 
?>
```

(omitted 'http' cause I can't post hyperlinks here as a new user).

But all I get is:

> There was a problem with the feed, try again later.

(translated from Danish error message).

Is it the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues in that code.
The first is you have a `<?php` inside an already opened `<?php` section. Concatenation is the answer to that problem.

The second is the function `single_cat_title()` **displays** the category title by default. Meaning it "echo()"s it out. So you need to tell that function to return the value not display it.

My solution would be to add a line of code above your include there to get the category you're looking for along the lines of:

```
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
```

The "false" tells the function to return it as a value instead of displaying it by default, the first parameter is the prefix or the text to display before the category title.

Then concatenate the current_category variable into your include statement

You can check out that function on the Template Tags page in the Wordpress Codex.